# flask_pymongo & bson problems on Manjaro Linux

Tags: python, flask, pymongo, manjaro

So I have a Flask project I am attempting to setup a dev environment for. I have successfully created this environment at least 3 or 4 times the exact same way on Mac & Ubuntu. I am attempting to setup the environment on Manjaro Linux and am getting I think maybe a versioning problem.

My setup process:

1. Install Anaconda.
2. Create a conda env with python=3.6 `conda create -n MyEnv python=3.6 pip`
3. activate said env and `pip install -r requirements.txt`
4. `python runwserver.py`

This has worked without issue on every other platform I used it on. But on Manjaro Linux I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runwserver.py", line 1, in <module>
    from wserver import app
  File "/home/user/Development/flask_project/wserver/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import wserver.appinit
  File "/home/user/Development/flask_project/wserver/appinit.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask.ext.pymongo import PyMongo
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 656, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 626, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/Py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/exthook.py", line 62, in load_module
    __import__(realname)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/Py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_pymongo/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from bson.errors import InvalidId
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/Py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bson/__init__.py", line 341
    except struct.error, e:
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

And here is my requirements.txt

```
alembic==0.8.2
bcrypt==3.1.1
cffi==1.8.3
et-xmlfile==1.0.1
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-Bcrypt==0.7.1
Flask-HTTPAuth==3.3.0
Flask-Login==0.3.0
Flask-Migrate==1.6.0
Flask-PyMongo==0.3.1
Flask-Script==2.0.5
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.0
Flask-WTF==0.12
gevent==1.1.2
greenlet==0.4.10
gunicorn==19.6.0
itsdangerous==0.24
jdcal==1.3
Jinja2==2.8
Mako==1.0.2
MarkupSafe==0.23
openpyxl==2.4.0
pip==10.0.1
pycparser==2.14
pymongo==2.9
pyserial==3.1.1
python-editor==0.4
python-dotenv==0.20.0
pytz==2015.6
setuptools==39.0.1
six==1.10.0
SQLAlchemy==1.0.8
Werkzeug==0.10.4
WTForms==2.0.2
boto3
botocore
```

Any help is appreciated.

--Edit--

So I just tried to recreate this problem with the fewest packages possible (per @UlrichEckhardt) and removing pymongo==2.9 from requirements.txt solved the problem!

Comment: What Python version were you using in the other envs?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I am using python 3.6 in all the other envs as well

Comment: Just to elaborate why I asked: Installation of that component using pip should have failed if the Python version doesn't match, so I thought that somehow the wrong version was used. The isolated env should take care of all dependencies. For a next step, you could extract a [mcve] and post that here.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt So I just tried doing that and found a (the) solution. Thanks for the input!